# GCP PubSub Replay historical messages to specific Subscription

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I have a **GCP PubSub Topic** and **multiple consuming applications**, with each app having its **own subscription** to it.

The max retention on Topic is **31 days** and messages are stored in a database. The use case is to allow specific **consumer app** to replay historical messages (i.e. **beyond 31 days**).

My plan is to write an API that a consumer app can call. This API will **retrieve messages** from the database and publish to **Topic**.

The problem with this approach is that all the consumer apps will receive a message instead of the specific app requesting a replay. How can I solve this, is there any better approach? Thanks.

Comment: Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter) help you?

Comment: Hi, thanks, don't think it does. To make it simple, let's say the consuming apps consume all messages from the Topic. So if Consumer A request replays, Consumer B also ends up getting the messages which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to restore messages from storage for only one subscription on a topic, there isn't going to be a straightforward way to do it on the existing topic and subscription. You could possibly use [filters](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter) as a means to accomplish it, but it'll still require an additional subscription. The process would be as follows:

1. Set up all of your normal subscriptions with a filter `NOT attributes:replay`.
2. When you do want to replay, create a new subscription on the topic that has a filter `attributes:replay`.
3. Have the consumer app that wants the replay create a subscriber on this second subscription in addition to its normal subscription.
4. Read the messages from storage and write them to the topic and add an attribute `replay` set to any value (e.g., `true`).
5. When the replay is complete, the consumer can stop reading from the new subscription and the subscription can be deleted.

There are some disadvantages to this setup using filters. When you do replay data, the other consumer apps will not get the messages, but you will be charged for Pub/Sub delivery as per how filtering costs work. If the replay of data is large enough and you have enough normal subscriptions, this could get expensive. Additionally, you'd have to stop and restart your consumer to create the subscriber on the new subscription in order for consumption to happen.

Alternatively, if your number of consumer applications per project is small enough and you can create a topic per consumer application, you could create a replay topic and subscription for each one. The consumer apps would always consume data from both the normal subscription and the replay subscription. The latter would normally not have any messages. If you do want to replay messages to a specific consumer app, you would read them from storage and publish them to the topic for that particular app.

The disadvantage here is that you have to manage an additional topic and subscription per consumer app. You'd need to ensure you don't run into the limit of 10,000 topics and 10,000 subscriptions per project. The advantage is that you wouldn't have to restart the consumer app in order to replay the messages, only publish to the appropriate topic. You'd also only be charged for the delivery of the messages once since the other consumer app subscriptions don't use the same topic and filter the messages out.

Comment: Thank you Kamal for taking time out to respond. I should have mentioned constraints, 1) Consuming apps can't create new Subscriptions at runtime (has to be created via terraform with a change ticket, due to org policy).  2) Consuming apps should receive replay messages from PubSub so they don't have to develop another interface.

Comment: I was thinking closely to what you have suggested. My idea is to use filters in slightly different way --> every Consuming app will define a filter with (NOT attributes.replay OR attributes:replay-requested-by: <app's subscription name>) 

The replay API will take requesting Consumer's Subscription name as input and will set two attributes on each replayed message: attributes:replay=true and attributes-replay-requested-by=<input.subscription-name>

Thus the replayed messages should be filtered out for all Consumers except the one requesting it.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the cost aspects, there will be atleast hundreds of Consumer apps, with atleast one Subscription to the Topic. I am not expecting replays to be often - they are meant to be used for recovery and occasional testing. Certainly, will consider. Creating a dedicated replay Topic per Consumer app could also be a good option from a cost perspective - it does mean more work for the Consumers though in terms of one time setup and listening to replay Topic.